# Python: import the containing package

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

In a module residing inside a package, i have the need to use a function defined within the `__init__.py` of that package. how can i import the package within the module that resides within the package, so i can use that function?

Importing `__init__` inside the module will not import the package, but instead a module named `__init__`, leading to two copies of things with different names...

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 47):

Also, starting in Python 2.5, relative imports are possible. e.g.:

```
from . import foo
```

Quoting from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references:

---

Starting with Python 2.5, in addition to the implicit relative imports described above, you can write explicit relative imports with the from module import name form of import statement. These explicit relative imports use leading dots to indicate the current and parent packages involved in the relative import. From the surrounding module for example, you might use:

```
from . import echo
from .. import formats
from ..filters import equalizer
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to import from `__init__.py`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: yet this is the way to import it; when you import the *package*, the `__init__.py` file serves as the effective namespace. You should never import `__init__.py` directly.

Answer (score 23):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I'm going to suggest that you move the function outside of the `__init__.py` file, and into another module inside that package. You can then easily import that function into your other module. If you want, you can have an import statement in the `__init__.py` file that will import that function (when the package is imported) as well.

Comment: i realise i can do this, it just seems rather messy and um, unpythonic.

Comment: Not sure how this is 'unpythonic'?  Wouldn't the alternative be even more messy, since __init__.py is not really a module?

Comment: +1 - using a `common.py` within your package is very usual practice in Python.

Comment: I've been messing around and haven't found any better way

Answer (score 5):

If the package is named `testmod` and your init file is therefore `testmod/__init__.py` and your module within the package is `submod.py` then from within `submod.py` file, you should just be able to say `import testmod` and use whatever you want that's defined in testmod.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what the situation is, but this may solve your "different name" problem:

```
import __init__ as top
top.some_function()
```

Or maybe?:

```
from __init__ import some_function
some_function()
```

Comment: This does work, but at least in cPython 2.7 the interpreter considers `__init__` to be a different module than `top`, and so the `__init__.py` file gets loaded twice.

Comment: This is an implicit relative import, and as such won't work in python 3, and is bad practice in python 2 anyway.

Comment: This still creates `sys.modules['__init__']`. Basically, the `__init__.py` module *should never be directly imported*. Import the package (the directory name) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, the file manage.py has `from django.core.management import execute_manager`, but `execute_manager` is not a module. It is a function within the `__init__.py` module of the `management` directory.