# Python -- import the package in a module that is inside the same package

Tags: python

I have a project structure something like this...

```
/some_app
    build/
    README
    out.py
    some_app/
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
        mod2.py
```

Now I want to import `some_app` package into `mod2`, without messing with `sys.path` trickery. What I simply did is...

```
# mod2.py
import some_app
```

Now when I run the mod2.py from the command line

```
some_app $ python mod2.py
```

it throws error `ImportError: No module named some_app`

BUT, inside the `out.py` file, when I do

```
# out.py
import some_app.mod2
```

and then do

```
some_app $ python out.py
```

it runs perfectly.

Hence, what is happening is this. I load a package in a module that is within the same package, and then run that module as the `__main__` file -- and it doesn't work. Next, I load the same module (the one that I ran as `__main__`) inside another module, and then run that another module as `__main__` -- and it works.

Can someone please elaborate on what's going on here?

**UPDATE**

I understand that there is no straightforward reason for doing this -- because I could have directly imported any modules inside the `some_app` package. The reason I am trying this is because, in the Django project, this is what they're doing. See [this file for example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py)

In every module, all the non-standard imports start with `django.`. So I wondered why and how they are doing that.

**UPDATE 2**

Relevant links

- [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)
- [Python: import the containing package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436497/python-import-the-containing-package)

Comment: It would help if you put some code to clarify the `__main__` thing.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`mod2.py` is part of `some_app`. As such, it makes no sense to import the module, since you're already inside it.

You can still `import mod1`. I'm assuming you need `some_app/__init__.py` to run. Not sure that's possible.

---

#### EDIT:

Looks like `from . import some_module` will do what you're after.

Comment: It's discouraged to use `from . import *`. But this does get at the right answer of `from . import mod2` inside `mod1.py`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Comment: I think I meant `*` as a wildcard here, not as literal syntax

Comment: `from . import some_module` throws `ImportError: cannot import name some_module` in Python 2.7, with or without `absolute_import`

Comment: You can also do `from .some_module import my_function` to only import the function you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `import some_app.mod2` from `out.py` because it is in the same directory that you have `some_app` package, and Python interpreter starts to look for modules from that path.

The import error in `mod2.py` is normal because there is not a `some_app` package in `mod2.py` folder.