# Why ModuleNotFound when importing a module in a same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

### Question

When I try to activate main.py on linux bash with the command as follows,

```
python3 main.py
```

The error message looking as below keeps appearing, and I cannot figure out why!!

```
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import folder_beta.util_one
File "folder_beta/util_one.py", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util_two'
```

### Questions in more detail

The folder tree looks like as below:

```
folder_alpha
├── main.py
└── folder_beta
      ├── __init__.py (empty)
      ├── util_one.py
      └── util_two.py
```

**main.py**

```
import folder_beta.util_one
import folder_beta.util_two
....
```

**util_one.py**

```
import util_two
...
```

When I executed the 'util_one.py' alone, it works perfectly fine but when I executed the main.py, the error keeps appearing.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a module from both within same package and from outside the package in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319423/import-a-module-from-both-within-same-package-and-from-outside-the-package-in-py)

Comment: When you run `main.py`, your package root path is `folder_alpha`.  When `util_one.py` try to `import util_two.py`, it is trying to find `util_two` in `folder_alpha` path.  Since it doesn't exist, Python returns a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an *implicit relative import*, it would have worked in Python 2 but it's no longer allowed in Python 3. From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python 3.

In `util_one.py` module, change it to:

```
from folder_beta import util_two
```

Comment: Should we write down "from folder_beta" even though util_one.py and util_two.py are in the same folder?

Comment: You can use explicit relative import as well, `from . import util_two`

Comment: @Eiffelbear You should consider your project structure when building the inner modules.  The modules will all use the project root as path.

Comment: @r.ook So the . in `from . import util_two` tells `util_one.py` to look up the `util_two.py` in the same directory, `folder_beta`, rather than upper directory, `folder_alpha`!

Comment: That's correct.  This might be a good reading for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time