# Why can't I import a module from both inside the module directory and outside it?

Tags: python

My current project has the following structure:

```
src:
   file1.py
   file2.py
```

There are some functions in file2 which I would like to import into file1 and use. So the file 1 has the following lines:

```
from file2 import func1, func2
```

When run the terminal in the src directory and type:

```
from file1 import *
```

everything works well. However, when go outside the directory src, and type in the python terminal

```
from src.file1 import *
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bhavincvts/Desktop/greenleap/solarAFD1/src/file1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from file2 import func1, func2 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'
```

After that, I tried changing the import statement to,

```
from .file2 import func1, func2
```

it then works well from outside the src folder. But when running the terminal inside the src folder, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bhavincvts/Desktop/greenleap/solarAFD1/src/file1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .file2 import func1, func2 
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: you are up for a long day understanding python imports, longstory short file1 ccan not see file2, (when running inside src your pythonpath can see it), put an \__init__.py file inside src and try again, with the from .file2 import ....

Comment: I would try what @E.Serra said... everytime I think I understand python imports I end up in a situation that boggles me..another option would be to just add src to your path

Comment: In short, you have to decide whether ``src`` is a package or not. That is, whether ``file2.py`` should be known as ``src.file2`` or just ``file2``. Doing both at the same time is not a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a module from both within same package and from outside the package in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319423/import-a-module-from-both-within-same-package-and-from-outside-the-package-in-py/50392363#50392363)

Comment: oh yes, I sort of understood that while I was writing the question. I was just wondering if there was some way you could use the file either way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it sort of does, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

got it;

file1.py:

```
from file2 import func1, func2
func1()
func2()
```

file2.py has the functions:

```
def func1():
    print('yeeeeah func1')

def func2():
    print('yeeeah func2')
```

src:
__init__.py
file1.py
file2.py

from src:

```
src$ python file1.py
```

Prints:

```
yeeeeah func1
yeeeah func2
```

from somewhere else:

```
src$ cd ..
test_stack$ python src/file1.py
```

Prints:

```
yeeeeah func1
yeeeah func2
```

Assuming src is your main directory (where setup.py requirements.txt etc live)

Comment: Yes, this works well for me too. However, if you try running a python terminal somewhere else (lets say in the directory containing the src folder), it'll throw you an error...

Comment: no, this works from src and from outside as long as you have the init.py file

Comment: @E.Serra Does your ``python`` point to Python *2*? Python3 removed implicit relative imports.

Comment: i am using python3, the __init__.py file indicates the directory can be usedd as a module

Answer (score -2):

In file1, before you import the functions from file2, you can specify the directory of file2:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path_to_the_directory_that_can_find_file2")

from file2 import func1, func2
```

This should make it more robust against running outside the src directory.

Comment: dont do this, it is bad practice, learn how to use proper imports

Comment: This might duplicate any module inside ``src``, which can lead to various non-obvious bugs (e.g. ``isinstance`` failing between the two versions).