# How to import without using sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a python3 project organized like this:

```
project
    src
        __init.py__
        file1.py (contains Class1)
        file2.py (contains Class2)
    test
        test1.py (contains TestClass1)
        test2.py (contains TestClass2)
```

I want to be able to import classes from `file1.py` into `file2.py` and from either `file1.py` or `file2.py` into `test1.py` and `test2.py`. What's the most straightforward way to accomplish this without setting `sys.path`?

I'm using python 3.7.

The code gets called as:

```
cd project/src/ && python3 file2.py
```

and as:

```
cd project/ && python3 -m unittest discover
```

This is an open-source project, so anyone who wants is welcome to the URL for our GitHub repo, but I expect it's not relevant to the question.

This ought not to be difficult but it's giving me fits. I've read the [Python3 import chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and searched for canonical Python project organization, to no avail.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `sys.path`? Could use set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running your tests?

Comment: That's a reasonable question. To me, sys.path seems like a hack. I find it difficult to believe there's not a more straightforward way to accomplish things in a simple project. Other languages, both older and newer than Python, have no difficulty with this.

Comment: This project structure looks weird. A setup like this means the package itself is called ``src`` – usually, ``src`` is a normal directory which *contains* the package. Why is there a ``src/__init__.py`` when ``src/file2.py`` gets executed directly? A package implies that ``file2.py`` gets executed as part of the package, e.g. ``python3 -m package.src.file2``. Which parts *are* the package and which ones are just directories?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a module from both within same package and from outside the package in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319423/import-a-module-from-both-within-same-package-and-from-outside-the-package-in-py)

Comment: Your link helps a lot, @MisterMiyagi - thanks! The "-m" flag is indeed the secret sauce. I now have something working. I'll play to document what I've got in an answer to my own question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I do not understand what it is about my project structure that looks weird. How would you structure a simple project? I've looked around for canonical Python directory structures but did not find much.

Comment: @AdamWildavsky The weird part is that your *package* appears to be named ``src``. Usually, ``src`` is a regular folder in which the actual package is. So instead of ``project/src/__init__.py``, one would have ``project/src/my_package/__init__.py``. Naming the package ``src`` is not wrong, just weird. Package layout and the ``src`` directory are [discussed in this blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure), for example.

Comment: I see now! Yes, it would seem weird if someone outside our project were to import our package, and I can't say that will never happen. Thanks again, @MisterMiyagi.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `__init__.py`

Python uses the presence of `__init__.py` files to determine which directories are Python packages. If you add these in your project like so:

```
project
    __init__.py
    src
        __init__.py
        file1.py (contains Class1)
        file2.py (contains Class2)
    test
        __init__.py
        test1.py (contains TestClass1)
        test2.py (contains TestClass2)
```

You should be able to import your source from your tests via the import path: `from project.src.file1 import Class1`.

Then run your tests with: `python -m unittest discover -s /path/to/project/test`

### Using `setuptools`

You could use `setuptools` to install your source then run something like this:

```
cd project/ && python3 -m pip install . && python3 -m unittest discover
```

You just need to add a `setup.py` file to the root of your project. For a simple `setup.py` script, you might want to refer to https://github.com/google/mobly/blob/master/setup.py (a project I used to use quite a bit). There are plenty of projects that use `setuptools` but many of them do pretty complicated setup and it can often be difficult to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not aware of setuptools. It seems like overkill for such a simple project. Appending to sys.path is less work, and that's still something I hope to avoid!

Comment: No prob! Unfortunately, outside of these three solutions, I don't think you'll find a simpler way to import python code outside of a given package tree. You could also consider putting an `__init__.py` in the root of your repo and naming your directories accordingly but that might require a larger refactor.

Comment: Thanks, @kingkupps. I'd be happy to add an __init__.py in the root directory if that would help! Can you give me a hint as to the import syntax I'd use if I do that?

Comment: Just updated my answer! You'll probably want to rename some of your project tree if you go with that route

Comment: Thanks! A friend who's not on StackOverflow suggested doing similarly. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: The **Using __init__.py** suggestion doesn't seem to work. I get this error when executing `python3 file2.py`:

  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

I did find an alternative, though - I'll post again tomorrow (Saturday.)

Comment: Aha! It will work if I invoke is as

`cd project/.. && python3 -m project.src.file2`

My alternative requires `python3 -m` as well.

Comment: Ah one thing I should specify is that when you run `python3 -m unittest discover -s project/test` make sure you are in the directory containing `project`. I set up the skeleton for that and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, thanks to the suggestions here and one from Alex Martelli. The secret sauce is the use of Python's **-m** flag.

```
project
    src
        __init.py__
        file1.py
            class Class1:
                pass
        file2.py
            from src.file1 import Class1
            class Class2:
                pass
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                # Instantiate Class2 here…
                pass
    test
        __init.py__
        test1.py
            from src.file1 import Class1
            class TestClass1:
                pass
        test2.py
            from src.file2 import Class2
            class TestClass2:
                pass
```

The app is invoked as `cd project && python3 -m src.file2`

The tests are run as `cd project && python3 -m unittest`