# How import module in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pycharm

I have two projects. In first one, I can import my module importme.py like:

```
import importme
```

And now I can use my function hello() in importme module without any problem. In second one, I recieve:

```
ImportError: No module named 'importme'
```

But I can import it via:

```
from . import importme
```

Why I cant import my module the same way in both projects? Should I configure some paths ?

**EDIT1**:

Directory structure of first project:

```
testproject/
├── importme.py
└── start.py
```

Directory structure of second project:

```
spiders/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
├── spider.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
├── download_page.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
├── importme.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
└── __init__.py
```

file **init**.py is empty.

Comment: Please add some overview on directory structure. And probably yes, there is something like `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I added dir structure of both projects under EDIT1.

Comment: so as You can see second project is package, so You should import it like this `from spiders import importme` . I just guess this *not working* one is this with `__init__`

Comment: and some other related SO question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647729

Comment: I import it from the same directory as main program is. In start.py I import importme.py. inspider.py I import importme.py. so what is the difference?

Comment: the question is how do You run these scripts ?

Comment: First one as `python3 start.py`. Second one  is run as `scrapy crawl <name of spider>`.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method of dealing with `PYTHONPATH` is installing package in edit mode in virtual environment.

1. Creating virtual environment

   ```
   # create
   $ python -m venv ~/virtualevns/myenv
   # then activate it
   $ source ~/virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate
   # you can check whether it got activated
   $ which python
   home/user/virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python
   ```
2. Writing `setup.py` for your project. For this refer to the official [distributing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) tutorial.
3. Installing package in editable format.

   If you install package with `-e` flag pip will install it in editable format meaning all changes you have in code will be present in your environment's package:

   ```
   $ cd mypkg
   $ pip install -e .
   ```
4. Finally you need to set your virtual-environment to be used in whatever IDE your editor you are using.

This is a great workflow because it's clean and reliable - you are using exactly what you'd be using in production/finished package environment.

Comment: I am using venv, but the problem is, that in first example, I can import module but in second one I cant. So my question is, why, where is the difference and how to solve it.