# Is it possible to access the variables in __init__.py from the modules in the same package?

Tags: python, package

I have a hello1 package that contains good.py module.

```
hello1
├── __init__.py
└── good.py
```

The **init** module has a variable `A = 1`, and I need to access the variable hello1.A in good.py.

```
import hello1

class Good(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print hello1.A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Good()
```

The issue is that when I execute the python script I got `ImportError: 'No module named hello1'` error. I could add `import sys; sys.path.append("..")` at the first line of `good.py` for a quick fix.

However, the good.py is in hello1 package where the __init__.py is also in, so I wonder if there is a way to access the variables in __init__.py from the modules in the same package.

Comment: Have you tried going to the directory containing `hello1` and running the script with `python hello1\good.py`? Also, you might find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436497/python-import-the-containing-package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Python: import the containing package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436497/python-import-the-containing-package):

Importing `__init__` seems to work fine.

```
import __init__

class Good(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print hello1.A
```

Comment: You should not import `__init__` directly. Instead, the parent directory of `hello1` should be listed in the python module search path and `hello1` should be imported instead.

Comment: If you use `python -m hello1.good` instead, then the current working directory is added to the path automatically; if that is the parent directory of `hello1` everything works just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Not always. If you have an executable located inside the package, and say the executable wants to lookup the package's version number located in __init__.py, this is exactly what you should do.

Comment: @Cerin: no, it is better to avoid putting executables in packages. In Python 3 you can now assign to the `__package__` variable to make relative imports work (see [PEP-366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)), after which you could use `from . import version`, but generally speaking you want to put your executables at the top level.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I couldn't disagree more. It's a common practice. Especially with tools which are implemented as *just* a package like `howdoi`.

Comment: @Cerin: You misunderstood me, I think. `howdoi` follows best practices, yes, by having `setuptools` create a console script (the executable) *outside* the package. So `howdoi/howdoi` is not the script, it is a module servicing the actual script, so `from . import __version__` works there because `howdoi` is still a package. *Nowhere in that package is there a `import __init__` present nor needed*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like sys.path.append(...) you could run your script as

```
python -m hello1.good
```

in the directory containing the "hello1"-directory or use the PYTHONPATH environment variable instead of sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you want to do something like:

```
python hello1/good.py
```

Since `good.py` is a submodule of a package you shouldn,'t run it directly; keep in mind that when directly executing it, then it isn't considered as part of the `hello1` package, which prevents relative imports and the current directory is the one that contains the file, hence `hello1` cannot be found if it isn't part of the `PYTHONPATH`. Instead you can run it using the `-m` switch of the python interpreter:

> `-m mod` : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

I personally don't like using the interpreter options to execute a python file. I'd rather have an independent launcher file `good.py` that imports the `hello1.good` module and uses it to do what it has to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicit import the constants you want to use.

It's preferable to have all your constants in a "config" file (i.e. config.py) ) and then if you want them in the package namespace, import them.

**init**.py file:

```
from package.config import *
```

it's more clear that way

Answer (score -1):

```
import __init__
```

...leads to: **No module named '**init**'**