# Importing __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying out the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274671/is-it-possible-to-access-the-variables-in-init-py-from-the-modules-in-the-sa).

The `__init__.py` file in a folder named `MyLibs` contains:

```
LogFile = r'D:\temp'
```

In `utils.py` in the *same folder* `MyLibs`, I tried various ways to access the `LogFile` variable:

```
from __init__ import *
print LogFile     #Gives: NameError: name 'LogFile' is not defined`:
```

and:

```
import __init__
print MyLibs.LogFile    #Gives: NameError: name 'MyLibs' is not defined
```

I got the errors while executing `from MyLibs.utils import *`

What is the fix I must do? I prefer a method where I can reference `LogFile` directly without having to add namespace prefixes.

Comment: `__init__.py` is a *package initialiser* and is not normally imported directly. Why are you not importing `MyLibl` *itself*?

Comment: That other question is giving you bad advice. I have left feedback on the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I found that the updated __init__.py was not called.  I needed to start a new session of Python for it to work.  False alarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake.

The updated `__init__.py` was somehow not executed.  I started a new Python session and it worked.

Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this with 2.7's implicit relative imports, but you could try this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import LogFile
```

If you're running the Python module directly, you need to run it with `python -m MyLibs.utils` rather than `python MyLibs/utils.py`.