# How to use __init__.py file in packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package as follows:

```
mypackage/
     __init__.py
     mod1.py
     mod2.py
```

Inside `mod1.py` I have a definition called `calculate()`. Now I am writing this code in `__init__.py` from mod1 import calculate

But everytime I write this code I am getting an error saying

> unresolved import calculate.

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you try `from .mod1 import calculate`?

Comment: Or, `from mypackage.mod1 import calculate`?

Answer (score 3):

You should import your modules from the package root folder as follows:

```
from mypackage.mod1 import calculate
```

Python uses the package name (e.g `mypackage` in your case) as a namespace, in which, it will look for the module `mod1`. Since you didn't tell python the `namespace` it didn't know where to look for your module, therefore yielded the error:

```
unresolved import calculate
```

The python documentation explains that in details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). You can also check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515197/python-import-module-from-a-package) thread for a detailed explanation on how package imports work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__.py`, you can import module using '.'

```
from .mod1 import calculate
```