# Python: relatively import the containing package

Tags: python, import, namespaces, relative-import

I have the following package structure (drastically simplified from a real use case):

```
mypackage/
├── __init__.py
├── mod1.py
│   ├── def func1(): return 1
│   └── ...
│
├── mod2.py
│   ├── def func2(): return 2
│   └── ...
└── mod3.py
```

with `__init__.py` like this

```py
from .mod1 import *
from .mod2 import *
```

Now, in `mod3.py` I want to access the *packages* complete namespace with one alias like `res = p.func1() + p.func2()` and I want this to achieve this by one relative import statement. Is this possible?

I **don't want** an absolute import like `import mypackage as p` (because the code should be indifferent on renaming the package).

Note, this is related to but different from [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436497/python-import-the-containing-package) from 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you do not want to use asterisks while doing imports so you can use this while still using relative import:

```
from . import mod1
```

You can call the function like this:

```
mod1.func1()
```

PS: If you are using Python 3 you are no longer required to use `__init__.py` to define packages.

Edit:
If you want use common namespace for all those functions you have imported you could create a new module to use as a header file:

```
mypackage/
├── header.py
│   ├── from .mod1 import *
│   └── from .mod2 import *
├── mod1.py
│   ├── def func1(): return 1
│   └── ...
│
├── mod2.py
│   ├── def func2(): return 2
│   └── ...
└── mod3.py
```

And in mod3.py you can import header.py and use the functions in various ways:

```
from .header import *
val1 = func1()
val2 = func2()
```

```
from . import header
val1 = header.func1()
val2 = header.func2()
```

```
from . import header as p
val1 = p.func1()
val2 = p.func2()
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want. I want to access the *whole package* under one alias. Because in reality my package imports more than two modules (`mod1` and `mod2`) and I don't want to keep track of which name comes from which module.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Actually, I thought of this my self and still hope for a more elegant solution. But anyway it mainly does what I want.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't be of more help :(