# Python: import the actual module object for the containing package, without naming it

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question or a close relative has been asked at least three times before ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436497/python-import-the-containing-package), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437382/python-relatively-import-the-containing-package), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286210/is-there-a-way-to-access-parent-modules-in-python)) but never, that I can find, satisfactorily answered; only workarounds are offered, and none of them work for my specific use case.

Suppose a directory structure like this:

```
mypackage/
├── __init__.py
└── mod.py
```

From `mod.py` I want to import `mypackage`.  Not any specific thing defined in `mypackage`, nor a sibling module, but the exact same object you would get if you
wrote `import mypackage` from outside the package.  And I want to do this without using the name `mypackage` (in case it might be renamed in the future).  How do I do that?

(You may assume that the containing package is *not* a namespace package.)

(You might think it would work to say `import __init__`, but that actually reloads `__init__.py` and creates a *separate* module object, `mypackage.__init__`, so that's no good.)

To reiterate, the answers to previous iterations of this question supply only workarounds (e.g. relatively importing only what you need from the containing package, or restructuring the code to avoid needing to refer to the containing package) that do not work for me.  **Please do not suggest any alternative approach.  Please answer the exact question I have asked.**

Comment: Does any of this answer what you are looking for?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286210/is-there-a-way-to-access-parent-modules-in-python

Comment: @mkrieger1 Of all of that, I think the only suggestion that could actually meet my requirements is `inspect.getmodule(f)` where `f` is a function defined directly by the package, but there aren't any such functions, so, no. (There are data objects, but I tried it and `inspect.getmodule(x)` for all such data objects returns None.)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45895490/) seems to work from what I can tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access parent modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286210/is-there-a-way-to-access-parent-modules-in-python)

Comment: @relent95 No, that is yet another case where (approximately) the same question was asked but the answers only offer workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can get the name of the containing package as a string by using `__package__`, or alternatively `__spec__.parent`, from within `mod.py`.

   See:

   - [What's the purpose of the "__package__" attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python)
   - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes
2. You can import the package given its name as a string by using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

Demo:

`__init__.py`

```
x = 5
```

`mod.py`

```
import importlib

p = importlib.import_module(__package__)
print(p)
print(p.x)
```

```
$ tree
.
└── mypackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mod.py

$ python3 -c 'import mypackage.mod'
<module 'mypackage' from '/tmp/…/mypackage/__init__.py'>
5
```